# Exporting a Silverlight grid to Excel sheet only writes 1 row

Tags: c#, silverlight, excel

I've a web silverlight app that lets the user select an excel file from their desktop, and adds 3 excel columns. This part works fine in a desktop app. but we need this as a web app. 
Now the web app is only writing the first row. I havew a 'Export' function to take what is on the grid and make an excel file.

```
     public void Export()
        {
            Presettings();

            string ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            //////dialog.DefaultExt = "*.xml";
            dialog.DefaultExt = "*.xls";
            //Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls
            dialog.Filter = "Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls";
            //////dialog.Filter = "Excel Xml (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == false)
                return;

            XmlWriterSettings myXmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            myXmlSettings.Indent = true;
            myXmlSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = false;

            using (XmlWriter myXML = XmlWriter.Create(dialog.OpenFile(), myXmlSettings))
            {

                var _with1 = myXML;

                _with1.WriteStartDocument();
                _with1.WriteProcessingInstruction("mso-application", "progid=" + '"' + "Excel.Sheet" + '"');
                _with1.WriteStartElement("Workbook", ss);

                _with1.WriteStartElement("DocumentProperties", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
                _with1.WriteElementString("Author", m_DocumentProperties.Author);
                _with1.WriteElementString("LastAuthor", m_DocumentProperties.LastAuthor);
                _with1.WriteElementString("Created", m_DocumentProperties.Created.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("LastSaved", m_DocumentProperties.LastSaved.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("Company", m_DocumentProperties.Company);
                _with1.WriteElementString("Version", m_DocumentProperties.Version);
                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                //Document Properties

                _with1.WriteStartElement("ExcelWorkbook", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
                _with1.WriteElementString("WindowHeight", m_WorkbookProperties.WindowHeight.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("WindowWidth", m_WorkbookProperties.WindowWidth.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("WindowTopX", m_WorkbookProperties.WindowTopX.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("WindowTopY", m_WorkbookProperties.WindowTopY.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("ProtectStructure", m_WorkbookProperties.ProtectStructure.ToString());
                _with1.WriteElementString("ProtectWindows", m_WorkbookProperties.ProtectWindows.ToString());
                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                //Excel Workbook

                _with1.WriteStartElement("Styles");


                for (int I = 0; I <= m_Styles.Count - 1; I++)
                {
                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Style");
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "ID", ss, m_Styles[I].ID);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Styles[I].Name))
                    {
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Name", ss, m_Styles[I].Name);
                    }

                    //ALIGNMENT LOGIC:
                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Alignment");

                    if ((m_Styles[I].Alignment != null))
                    {
                        if (m_Styles[I].Alignment.Horizontal != 0)
                        {
                            _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Horizontal", ss, m_Styles[I].Alignment.Horizontal.ToString());
                        }

                        if (m_Styles[I].Alignment.Vertical != 0)
                        {
                            _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Vertical", ss, m_Styles[I].Alignment.Vertical.ToString());
                        }

                        if (m_Styles[I].Alignment.WrapText == true)
                        {
                            _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "WrapText", ss, "1");
                        }

                    }

                    _with1.WriteEndElement();

                    //BORDER LOGIC:
                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Borders");

                    if (!(m_Styles[I].Borders.Count == 0))
                    {
                        for (int J = 0; J <= m_Styles[I].Borders.Count - 1; J++)
                        {
                            ExcelBorder myBorder = m_Styles[I].Borders[J];


                            if (myBorder.Position == Excel.Styles.Position.All)
                            {
                                _with1.WriteStartElement("Border");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Position", ss, "Bottom");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "LineStyle", ss, myBorder.LineStyle.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Weight", ss, myBorder.Weight.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                                //Border

                                _with1.WriteStartElement("Border");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Position", ss, "Left");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "LineStyle", ss, myBorder.LineStyle.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Weight", ss, myBorder.Weight.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                                //Border

                                _with1.WriteStartElement("Border");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Position", ss, "Right");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "LineStyle", ss, myBorder.LineStyle.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Weight", ss, myBorder.Weight.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                                //Border

                                _with1.WriteStartElement("Border");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Position", ss, "Top");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "LineStyle", ss, myBorder.LineStyle.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Weight", ss, myBorder.Weight.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                                //Border

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _with1.WriteStartElement("Border");
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Position", ss, myBorder.Position.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "LineStyle", ss, myBorder.LineStyle.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Weight", ss, myBorder.Weight.ToString());
                                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                                //Border
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    _with1.WriteEndElement();
                    //Borders

                    //FONT LOGIC:
                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Font");
                    ExcelFont myFont = m_Styles[I].Font;
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "FontName", ss, myFont.FontName.ToString());
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Size", ss, myFont.Size.ToString());
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Color", ss, myFont.Color.ToString().Remove(1, 2));
                    if (myFont.Bold == true)
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Bold", ss, "1");
                    if (myFont.Italic == true)
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Italic", ss, "1");
                    if (myFont.Underline != 0)
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Underline", ss, myFont.Underline.ToString());
                    _with1.WriteEndElement();

                    ExcelInterior myInterior = m_Styles[I].Interior;
                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Interior");
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Color", ss, myInterior.Color.ToString().Remove(1, 2));
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Pattern", ss, "Solid");
                    _with1.WriteEndElement();

                    _with1.WriteStartElement("NumberFormat");
                    _with1.WriteEndElement();

                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Protection");
                    _with1.WriteEndElement();

                    _with1.WriteEndElement();
                    //Style

                }

                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                //Styles


                //WORKSHEETS:
                Worksheet myWorksheet = m_Worksheets[0];
                _with1.WriteStartElement("Worksheet");
                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Name", ss, myWorksheet.Name);

                _with1.WriteStartElement("Table");
                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "ExpandedColumnCount", ss, myWorksheet.Table.ExpandedColumnCount.ToString());
                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "ExpandedRowCount", ss, Convert.ToString(myWorksheet.Table.ExpandedRowCount + 100));
                //Temporary fix: sometimes 1 row is not added.
                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "FullColumns", ss, myWorksheet.Table.FullColumns.ToString());
                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "FullRows", ss, Convert.ToString(myWorksheet.Table.FullRows + 100));
                //Temporary fix: sometimes 1 row is not added.
                _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "DefaultRowHeight", ss, myWorksheet.Table.DefaultRowHeight.ToString());

                for (int J = 0; J <= myWorksheet.Table.Columns.Count - 1; J++)
                {
                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Column");
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "AutoFitWidth", ss, myWorksheet.Table.Columns[J].AutoFitWidth.ToString());
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Width", ss, myWorksheet.Table.Columns[J].Width.ToString());
                    _with1.WriteEndElement();
                }


                for (int J = 0; J <= myWorksheet.Table.Rows.Count - 1; J++)
                {
                    Row myRow = myWorksheet.Table.Rows[J];

                    _with1.WriteStartElement("Row");
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Index", ss, Convert.ToString(myRow.Index + 1));
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "AutoFitHeight", ss, myRow.AutoFitHeight.ToString());
                    _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Height", ss, myRow.Height.ToString());
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myRow.StyleID))
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "StyleID", ss, myRow.StyleID);


                    for (int K = 0; K <= myRow.Cells.Count - 1; K++)
                    {
                        _with1.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Index", ss, myRow.Cells[K].Index.ToString());
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myRow.Cells[K].StyleID))
                            _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "StyleID", ss, myRow.Cells[K].StyleID);
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "MergeAcross", ss, myRow.Cells[K].MergeAcross.ToString());
                        _with1.WriteStartElement("Data");
                        _with1.WriteAttributeString("ss", "Type", ss, myRow.Cells[K].Type);
                        _with1.WriteValue(myRow.Cells[K].Value);
                        _with1.WriteEndElement();
                        //Data
                        _with1.WriteEndElement();
                        //Cell

                    }

                    _with1.WriteEndElement();
                    //Row

                }

                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                //Table
                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                //Worksheet

                //ADD WORKSHEET OPTIONS [TO BE ADDED IN THE FUTURE].
                //sw.WriteLine("  <WorksheetOptions xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"">")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <PageSetup>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <Header x:Margin=""0.3""/>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <Footer x:Margin=""0.3""/>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <PageMargins x:Bottom=""0.75"" x:Left=""0.7"" x:Right=""0.7"" x:Top=""0.75""/>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   </PageSetup>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <Unsynced/>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <Print>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <ValidPrinterInfo/>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <HorizontalResolution>300</HorizontalResolution>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <VerticalResolution>300</VerticalResolution>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   </Print>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <Selected/>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <Panes>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    <Pane>")
                //sw.WriteLine("     <Number>3</Number>")
                //sw.WriteLine("     <ActiveRow>26</ActiveRow>")
                //sw.WriteLine("    </Pane>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   </Panes>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>")
                //sw.WriteLine("   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>")
                //sw.WriteLine("  </WorksheetOptions>")

                _with1.WriteEndElement();
                //Workbook
                _with1.WriteEndDocument();
                _with1.Close();


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only looping through the rows in the Worksheet:

```
for (int J = 0; J <= myWorksheet.Table.Rows.Count - 1; J++)
```

You need to loop through the rows in the Silverlight grid instead.

Comment: May be but one thing is this works with sample data but not actual excel:testdata obj = null;
this.LstData = new List<testdata>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
obj = new testdata();
obj.ID = i;
obj.FirstName = "First Name " +i.ToString();
obj.LastName = "Last Name " + i.ToString();
obj.Address1 = "Address 1 "+i.ToString();
obj.Address1 = "Address 2 " + i.ToString();
obj.City = "City " + i.ToString();
obj.Phone = "Phone " + i.ToString();
obj.Mobile = "Mobile" + i.ToString();
this.LstData.Add(obj);
}

Comment: Can you paste this into an update on your question? Hard to read this here and understand.